# How to insert Adsterra ad between content in WkWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

i made ios app with my Wordpress Website using Rest api to display content in WkWebView. now what is want is to display Adsterra network ad after half content and i have written code like this..

```
let htmlString: String = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"> body {font-family: \"SFUIText-Regular\"; text-align: justify;  } img { max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; } iframe { max-width: auto; width: auto; height: auto; }</style> </head><body>" + self.webContent + "</body></html>"

let halfwayIndex = htmlString.index(htmlString.startIndex, offsetBy: htmlString.count / 2)

let htmlBeforeAd = String(htmlString.prefix(upTo: halfwayIndex))
let htmlAfterAd = String(htmlString.suffix(from: halfwayIndex))

//Ad Code Here
let adCode = "<div><script type=\"text/javascript\"> atOptions = { 'key' : '6d9a5a16b8cff8984586ef********', 'format' : 'iframe', 'height' : 250, 'width' : 300, 'params' : {} }; document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//www.profitablecreativeformat.com/6d9a5a16b8cff******ef06b5afd1be/invoke.js\"></scr' + 'ipt>'); </script></div>"

let htmlStringWithAd = htmlBeforeAd + adCode + htmlAfterAd
self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStringWithAd, baseURL: nil)
```

when is use

````
let adCode = "<div>your ad code here</div>"
`

i can see "your ad code here" after half content but not the ad.. can anyone please help me out ?

i have also tried 

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>`

and this:

    ```
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    
    ```
can anyone help me out ??
````